# U-Net pytorch model outputting nan for MSE but not L1?

Tags: pytorch

I’m training a U-Net (model below) on 10 different datasets.
When I train using L1 loss, I receive no errors however, for one of the datasets using MSE loss the network outputs tensor[nan…] and cannot train after ~5-10th epoch. I have tried gradient clipping with arbitrary values of 0.5 and 1 - neither worked. I've also checked and none of the inputs contain nan values

Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN,self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(config.numinputs, 64,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64))
    
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential( 
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64))
        
        self.layer3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, padding=0))
            
        self.layer4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64,128,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128))

        self.layer5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128))
            
        self.layer6 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, padding=0))
            
        self.layer7 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 256,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256))
            
        self.layer8 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256))
            
        self.layer9 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256))
            
        self.layer10 = nn.UpsamplingBilinear2d(scale_factor=2)
            
        self.layer11 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 128,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128))
            
        self.layer12 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128))
            
        self.layer13 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 128,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128))
            
        self.layer14 = nn.UpsamplingBilinear2d(scale_factor=2)
            
        self.layer15 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(128, 64,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64))
            
        self.layer16 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 64,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64))
            
        self.layer17 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(64, 1,kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(1))
        
        self.layer18 = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
            
            
    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.layer1(x)  
        x = self.layer2(x)  
        x = self.layer3(x)  
        x = self.layer4(x)
        x = self.layer5(x)
        x = self.layer6(x)  
        x = self.layer7(x)
        x = self.layer8(x)
        x = self.layer9(x)  
        x = self.layer10(x)  
        x = self.layer11(x)  
        x = self.layer12(x)  
        x = self.layer13(x)  
        x = self.layer14(x)  
        x = self.layer15(x)  
        x = self.layer16(x)
        x = self.layer17(x) 
        x = x.view(1, -1)
        x = self.layer18(x)
        x = x.reshape(1, 512, 512)
        
        return x
```

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, nor MSE or L1 losses are suited to train a U-net, mainly because this model performs semantic segmentation and outputs a probability distribution.

Loss functions such as *Categorical/Binary*-Cross Entropy or Focal Loss (if you have class imbalance) will definitely give you better results!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm training a unet for heatmap regression (i.e. probability distribution) rather than semantic segmentation. From what I found in papers, L1 and MSE are used, but there are others (which I am trialling but wanted to do MSE to compare). Thanks anyways!